# Daemon to synchronize local directory with Amazon S3 (AMI using Ubuntu Linux and PHP)

Tags: php, linux, amazon-s3

are there any solutions to keep synchronized an AMI's local directory with an S3 bucket?

The idea is to be able to deploy a standard LAMP webapp (and it's user file uploads) without the need to alter the current code.

I can imagine something like a daemon updating "AMI's local directory" <-> "S3'sBucket"

I know this is not a scalable/efficient solution in the long run, but it would provide a **quick**-n-dirty solution for my current needs (to deploy a webapp in many Amazon's EC2 instances with DB replication).

A better (if not perfect) solution would be if local directory would be somehow 'symbolic' (like symbolic/hard links) and not actually phisically consuming space; but seamlessly accesible from a standar webapp.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this solves my question, I haven't tried it yet, but it looks like what I was looking for.

http://ikorolchuk.blogspot.com/2012/02/mount-amazon-s3-storage-as-local.html